# How do a I remove a specific query string in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, apache2.4

Hello and thanks in advance...

I have a situation where I need to completely remove the query string if it matches a pattern. I've been searching for an answer or even something close. So far, no luck. I've even tried a few things in my htaccess but without success.

The specific query string I need to remove is `?fbclid=` and everything that comes after it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what your actual issue is, since you did not share your attempts so far. So we cannot help with those. All I can offer is another example. No idea if that helps.

This implements an internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fbclid=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD]
```

Here the variant for an external redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fbclid=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301]
```

It always is a good idea to start out with a temporary 302 redirection and to only change that to a 301 once you are sure the current solution is final.

Comment: Thanks for you help, the issue was I have tried a number of things and all failed. The part I was missing is the `RewriteCond` part. Your example is perfect!

Comment: The only other question I have at the moment, and not sure if it warrants a separate post is the "order" of things. Right now I placed the new lines just below a section of htaccess that handles http->https and cpanel SSL cert updates.

Comment: Separate questions should be asked separately, reason is that others, finding answers here prefer focused questions and answers, for obvious reasons. But nothing speaks against a quick shot: you certainly can place such rules as above below http to https redirections, that actually is the typical order.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep in mind the separation of the questions in the future.